# How to create a user generated matrix in javascript/html while having the table label each cell incrementally

Tags: javascript, html, matrix, html-table, nested-loops

Well hello hello everyone, new to javascript. I received an assignment and am at a bit of a standstill. I need to have a user-generated table that labels itself. I am having a hard enough time getting the table to generate properly with the input from prompts. Now I am also stuck with the loop needed for the labeled rows and columns as well. It May seem ridiculous how simple this is but I am exhausted and receiving little guidance and could use the help.

The table should look like this. I can't even get the table to generate properly with loops yet. 
[1][2][3][4]
[5][6][7][8]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script>
 var row = prompt("how many rows would you like?");
 var col = prompt("how many colums would you like?");
</script>
```

```
<body>
  <script>
    var mytable = "";
    var cellNum = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < row ; r++);
    {
      mytable += "<tr>";
       for (var c = 0 ; c < col; c++ );
      {
        mytable += "<td>" + cellNum++; + "</td>";
      }
    mytable += "</tr>";

    }

  document.write("<table border=1>" + mytable + "</table>");
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of `document.write()` you should try and use some DOM manipulating methods like `document.createElement()` and `parentNode.append()` or simply redefine the `element.innerHTML` property of a target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically put a semicolon behind the first for loop.

```
for (var c = 0 ; c < col; c++ );
```

Right version would be this piece of code:

```
for (var c = 0 ; c < col; c++ )
```

I also would change

```
for (var r = 0; r < row ; r++)
```

into

```
for (var r = 0; r < row-1 ; r++)
```

or you gonna end up with a empty row.

Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you! That semicolon has caused me a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

just remove semicolons from the for loop.

```js
var mytable = "";
var cellNum=0, row=3, col=4;
    for (var r = 0; r < row ; r++) {
      mytable += "<tr>";
       for (var c = 0 ; c < col; c++ ) {
        mytable += "<td>" + (++cellNum) + "</td>";
      }
    mytable += "</tr>";

    }

  document.write("<table border=1>" + mytable + "</table>");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. That (++cellNum)  solved my issue of the first row being a 0 instead of a 1! brilliant thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the answer has already been put above. Just a fun take from my side as well.

How about we create some huge amount of cells and show only part of them depending on input. I've used `flex` container to conditionally set styles.

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/42c1mep8/30/

Cheers!